# How to free memory to a pointer in c

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

I have this (bad) code

```
void function(deq** dq, int data)
{
  // TODO: add a new element at the end of the queue
  deq *temp = (dequeue*)malloc(sizeof(dequeue));
  deq *copy = (*dq);
  temp->data = data;


  if (copy == NULL) {
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    (*dq) = temp;
  }
  else{
    while (copy->next != NULL) {
      copy = copy->next;
    }

    temp->prev = copy;
    temp->next = NULL;
    copy->next = temp;
    (*dq) = temp;
  }

  //free(temp);
}
```

what is my problem is that i can not free temp without crashing the programm is there a way to solve this ? and can someone tell me why whenn i use this free i can't run the program but with valgrind it works ... so funny.

```
==17186== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17186==     in use at exit: 216 bytes in 9 blocks
==17186==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 6 frees, 360 bytes allocated
==17186== 
==17186== 72 (24 direct, 48 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 9
==17186==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17186==    by 0x400670: dequeue_push_front (dequeue.c:12)
==17186==    by 0x400A1D: main (main.c:21)
==17186== 
==17186== 144 (24 direct, 120 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 9
==17186==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17186==    by 0x400670: dequeue_push_front (dequeue.c:12)
==17186==    by 0x400BA3: main (main.c:48)
==17186== 
==17186== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17186==    definitely lost: 48 bytes in 2 blocks
==17186==    indirectly lost: 168 bytes in 7 blocks
==17186==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17186==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17186==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17186== 
==17186== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17186== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Why are you both outputting the address via `*dq` and freeing it at the end of the function?

Comment: i know that free is bad, but if i comment it out, then i get those memory leaks

Comment: `free` is **not** bad.  It's what you're supposed to do to clean up after yourself.  It just needs to be done properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to `free(temp)` in this function.

This function is allocating `temp` on the heap using `malloc`, then the node is placed in a list.  If you `free()` the memory you just allocated here, you're left with a node in the list that points to invalid memory.  Referencing that node leads to undefined behavior, which in this case manifests in a core dump.

The proper time to call `free()` is when a node is removed from the list.

As for the memory leak, that's happening in the `else` block.

You place `temp` at the end of the list, but then you overwrite the head of the list with `temp`, so your only reference to the rest of the list is in the `prev` pointer of `temp`.  However, since that is now your new head, you probably don't bother to look at `prev` when cleaning up.  So you have a memory leak.

To fix the leak, get rid of the assignment to `*dq`:

```
...
else {
    while (copy->next != NULL) {
      copy = copy->next;
    }

    temp->prev = copy;
    temp->next = NULL;
    copy->next = temp;
}
...
```

Comment: i have a destroy function that loops to the nodes and deletes them but still get memory leaks, and valgrind tells me this

Comment: '==17186== 72 (24 direct, 48 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 9
==17186==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17186==    by 0x400670: dequeue_push_front (dequeue.c:12)
==17186==    by 0x400A1D: main (main.c:21)
==17186== '

Comment: hm... when i use this i get bad result, just 000 but it should be numbers

Comment: @twistedhat That problem isn't in the posted code.  We need to see your full code.

Comment: so you think the problem is somewhere else ? i can't post the full code to big and it is private project for collage.

Comment: @twistedhat Then trim the code down to a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  At this point, I believe the question about the memory leak has been addressed, so you should accept one of the answers here and post a new question regarding the invalid output.

Comment: you were right, the error was not in this function. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `free(temp)` but continue to use the value of `temp` in the lines

```
(*dq) = temp;
```

and

```
copy->next = temp;
```

Don't call `free(temp)`. Make sure to free all memory in the calling function by traversing the linked list and calling `free` on all the nodes.

Accessing memory after it has been `free`d is cause for undefined behavior.

BTW, the second time you use

```
(*dq) = temp;
```

leads to memory leaks. Remove that line.